# Error importing .pyd, works if it is renamed to .so

Tags: python, module

I'm creating a Python library file from C++ using Boost::Python, and I'm trying to import it from the Python command line to test it.

The module seems to work correctly when imported, but only if it is named `.so`. If the same exact file is renamed to `.pyd`, in the same directory, the console replies with an

```
ImportError: No module named Test
```

I have also tried to rename it with a trailing `_d` in case the console was in debug mode, but that does not seem to be the case.

What could be the problem?

Comment: Not 100% sure, but if you're using C++/boost, you probably end up with an so library indeed. Don't name it `.pyd`; I've never come across that extension.

Comment: What's your OS though? A quick search shows `.pyd` for Windows, while `.so` (instead of `.dll`) is *nix, afaik.

Comment: @Evert It was my understanding that the two were basically the same thing.. maybe that's true only for Windows? I assumed that `.pyd` was to make it clearer that it was a library meant for python. If that is wrong then I will avoid it (if you want to put that as an answer I'll accept it).

Comment: Yes, that's what the official docs say: dll and pyd are the same, and pyd is preferred. But that implies this only works on Windows, hence my OS question.

Comment: @Evert As you have probably guessed I'm on Linux (Ubuntu)